# unicode, not str in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I tried to run this Python code:

```
with io.open(outfile, 'w' ) as processed_text, io.open(infile, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        processed_text.write(preprocess(line.rstrip())+'\n')
```

but got `TypeError: must be unicode, not str`

How can i solve this problem? I searched here for similar problems and found one to try like

```
with io.open(outfile, 'w', encoding="utf-8") as processed_text, io.open(infile, 'r') as fin:
```

but didn't work.

Comment: Please edit your question with an example of your files (outfile and infile)

Comment: looks like your `preprocess` function return an `str` instead of a `unicode`.

Comment: i edited the post with preprocess

Comment: Still not clear, what does `tokenize` return? The bottom line is that you need to write a `unicode` string when using `io.open`, if `preprocess` is returning an `str`, just add `.decode('utf8')` to convert it to unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Note](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html):

> Since this module has been designed primarily for Python 3.x, you have to be aware that all uses of “bytes” in this document refer to the str type (of which bytes is an alias), and all uses of “text” refer to the unicode type. Furthermore, those two types are not interchangeable in the io APIs.

```
In [1]: import io

In [2]: def preprocess(s):
   ...:     return bytes(s)
   ...: 

In [3]: with io.open('tst1.out', 'w') as processed_text, io.open('tst1', 'r') as fin:
   ...:     for line in fin:
   ...:         try:
   ...:             out_line = unicode(preprocess(line.rstrip() + '\n'), 'utf-8')
   ...:         except TypeError:
   ...:             out_line = preprocess(line.rstrip() + '\n')
   ...:         processed_text.write(out_line)
```

Comment: Thanks for your replying , i tried your commnds but problem still , excuse me you mean if i upgrade version of python , this error will be solved

Comment: I mean `str` in python2 is `bytes` and in python3 it is `unicode`. Apparently your `preprocess()` does something with the input, so it becomes `bytes` type, hence the error.

Comment: Did you try my other suggestion?

Answer (score 5):

Try putting this at the very top of your file:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

Python 3.x uses unicode by default. This will cause Python 2.x to follow the same behavior.

If you still have issues you can manually cast the problem string ala

```
uni_string = unicode(my_string)
```

Comment: Where is it failing? Find the input string that is causing the problem and cast it to unicode like this: unicode(mystring)

Answer (score 1):

Try writing u in front of the processed string e.g. [u'blah']

Comment: thanks for replying , excuse me where can i write u ? in the file i want to process it ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you write a `unicode` string when opening a file using `io.open`. Something like this should do the trick:

```
with io.open(outfile, 'w' ) as processed_text, io.open(infile, 'r') as fin:
    for line in fin:
        s = preprocess(line.rstrip())
        if isinstance(s, str):
            s = s.decode('utf8')
        processed_text.write(s + u'\n')
```

Or modify `preprocess` to make sure it returns a `unicode` string.